# Test class in salesforce of following wrapper controller

Tags: unit-test

I created a controller which looks like this

```
public class CustomAccountController {
 
    public Account acc{get;set;}
    private Id  AccId{get;set;}
    public contactwrapper objconwrap{get;set;}
    public List<contactwrapper> contactList{get;set;}
    public contact newCont{get;set;}

    public CustomAccountController() {
        try {
            AccId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
            if(AccId != null) {
                acc = [select Name,Description,NumberOfEmployees,Phone,Website,Industry from Account where id = :AccId];
                initContact(acc);
            } else {
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error, 'Please pass parameter to this page. For eg. /apex/CustomAccount?id=0019000000OKdsH'));
            }   
        } catch(Exception e) {
            apexPages.addMessages(e);
        }      **strong text**
    }
     
    public void initContact(Account acc) {
        if(acc != null) {
            contactList = new  List<contactwrapper>();
            for(Contact c : [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email from Contact where AccountID =: acc.Id]) {
                contactList.add(new ContactWrapper(c));
            }
        }
    }
    public pageReference save() {
        try {
            List<contact> contactToUpdate = new  List<contact>();
            for(ContactWrapper c: contactList) {
                if(c.isSelected) {
                    contactToUpdate.add(c.cont);
                }
            }     
            update contactToUpdate;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            apexPages.addMessages(e);
        }    
        return null;
    }
     
    public pageReference delet() {
        try {
            List<contact> contactToDelete = new  List<contact>();
            for(ContactWrapper c: contactList) {
                if(c.isSelected) {              
                    contactToDelete.add(c.cont);
                }
            }
            delete contactToDelete;
            initContact(acc);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            apexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
        return null;
    }    
     
    public pageReference newContact() {
        newCont = new Contact(AccountId = accId);
        return null;
    } 
     
    public pageReference saveNewContact() {
        try {
            upsert newCont;
            newCont = null;
            initContact(acc);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            apexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
        return null;
    }  
     public class ContactWrapper{
        public Contact cont { get; set; }
        public boolean isSelected{ get; set; }
        
       public ContactWrapper(Contact c) {
            cont = c;
            isSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I just make test class of above controller class but code coverage reaches 76% now i want to increase the code coverage..so what possible change i can do so i can reach at least 95% or above

Here is my @isTest Class

```
@isTest
   Public class TestCustomAccountController{
   Static TestMethod void TestCustomAccountController(){
    PageReference pageRef = Page.wrapper8;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    Account acc = new Account(name='vivek112');
    insert acc;
    ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id',acc.id);
    Contact con = new Contact(FirstName='vivek112', AccountId = acc.Id);
    List<Contact> lstcon = new List<Contact>();
    lstcon.add(con);                
    CustomAccountController objCustom = new CustomAccountController ();
    CustomAccountController.ContactWrapper objwrap = new     CustomAccountController.ContactWrapper(con);
    objCustom.initContact(acc);
    objCustom.save();
    objCustom.delet();
    objCustom.newContact();
    objCustom.savenewContact(); 
  }
 }
```

So what can i change to increase to code coverage...
Snapshot of developer console...........
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are some of the problems you run into when writing the test code?

Comment: I just make test class of above controller class but code coverage reaches 76% now i want to increase the code coverage..so what possible change i can do so i can reach at least 95% or above

Comment: Using the developer console, you can find out exactly which parts of your code are covered and which are not.

Comment: So As per My test class it's a proper way or not if yes then how to increase the code coverage of above controller...Please...

Comment: You need to let us know which lines are not covered in the test class and we can suggest ways of improving the coverage

Answer (score 4):

You need to write test code that will trigger each path through your code. I.e. Both sides of if/else statements, try/catch statements, etc.

For example to cover line 16 in your developer console screenshot the following should do the job:

```
@isTest
public class TestCustomAccountController
{
    @isTest
    public static void TestCustomAccountControllerNoID()
    {
        PageReference pageRef = Page.wrapper8;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        // Do not set the ID parameter
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'vivek112');
        Contact con = new Contact(FirstName = 'vivek112');
        CustomAccountController objCustom = new CustomAccountController ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply....so as per your reply i solved the id problem...now how can i solve the wrapper variable as per in the snapshot line 35....

Comment: And Also How can i solve the line no 27 in snapshot of developer console....please any one help me...i just tried many times...but it is not covered..Please!!

Comment: To trigger line 35 you need to ensure that `c.IsSelected` is `true` in one of your tests.

To trigger line 27 you need to have at least one Contact attached to the Account. e.g.
`Account acc = new Account(Name='vivek112'); Contact con = new Contact(FirstName='vivek112', AccountId = acc.Id);`

Comment: Thanks for Reply..The id issued was solved.Here i just modify my test class as per your instruction display above...after that i face same issued..

Comment: Sir Please make test class for the above controller so i can understand the fully flow of the test class..